# Django-herald: Can't send mails with attachments

Tags: python, django

Anyone using Django herald for sending notifications?

I've been struggling for days to make it work but the lack of documentation and silent failures made it impossible to debug the issues. It seems that the mails are not being sent if I include an attachment in it.

```
from herald.base import EmailNotification


def sendMail():
    SendThisMail(user, my_modal).send(user=my_user) # creates an error on this line as the file object is closed and inaccessible.

@registry.register_decorator()
class SendThisMail(SomeBaseClass, EmailNotification):
    def __init__(self, user, my_modal: models.MyModal):
        super().__init__(user, my_modal)

        self.subject = "abc"

        file = open('.staticfiles/assets/some.pdf', 'rb')

        self.attachments = [('attachment_1', File(file))]

        self.context = {
            **self.context,
            'subject': self.subject,
            'attachment': self.attachments,
        }

        self.to_emails = [user.email]
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the project docs:

> Each attachment in the list can be one of the following:
>
> 1. A tuple which consists of the filename, the raw attachment data, and the mimetype. It is up to you to get the attachment data

So the relevant parts of your code code should be something like:

```py
  data = open('.staticfiles/assets/some.pdf', 'rb').read()
  self.attachments = [('attachment_1', data, 'application/pdf')]
```

Comment: Jesus F. Christ, it worked! Finally, I can get some sleep. I tried the same in the very first attempt and it didn't work for some reason. Oddly it worked now :|

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Now I understood why it didn't work the first time - I was using `with open(...)` to read the file and as soon as I left the `with` block, the file was closed, breaking the code.

I have a doubt with the current approach. The file here remains open. Where do I close the file and how?